# Is it faster to detect almost zeros and replace them for 0.0 or leave them as small numbers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, math, numerical-methods

I am programming a numerical analysis program and sometimes the calculus give in some of the coefficients really small numbers i.e `a0=1.234542e-12`

If I calculate an array of 10 values (from which i.e. 6 of them are small numbers) and later on I multiply each of them by t^x (just as an example)
being x=1:10, what is faster computationally?

- just leave the small number as they are
- Detect numbers that are lower than `threshold` and substitute them by 0.0

The question is mainly because maybe the compiler just doesn't make the calculus of a number multiplied by 0 because it always is 0, or it may just multiply it and I am making the program slower for adding `if` conditionals just to check if a number is 0 or not.

Comment: For an array of 10 numbers you will see no difference whatsoever.

Comment: You should value correctness over speed.

Comment: Well, a value multiplied by zero is zero, while a value multiplied by a small value is another small value. In a long chain of calculations the end result may be vastly different depending on if you replace the small value with zero.

Comment: @Oded Yes, of course correctness over speed, but when I know the program should give me a 1.0 very often it gives me 1.00000001, even if the EXACT correct result is 1.0 (checked by hand and by matlab), so I guessed that 1.0e-12 has to be a numerical calculus error. Testing my software this kind of minimal numerical errors over time they always converge to a result where instead to be 0 is also of order 1.0e-12 (usually they multiply themselves or other small values). so my question goes in the same direction still. Which one is faster?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yes! but it is only an example. what if 12000 values?

Comment: @Oded: It depends on how correct you'd like to have it. E.g. physically based ray tracers typically only use approximations that on average converge towards the correct result; correct, i.e. analytical solutions are generally too slow or even impossible.

Comment: i think even for 12000 numbers you will have almost no difference in speed

Comment: I suspect that using VS2008, floating point arithmetic will take a fixed time regardless of the values involved, so multiplying by zero takes just as long as multiplying by a small number. But I haven't tested. If you care, you should test. I really don't think the compiler will replace `x * some_slow_function()` with `x == 0 ? x : x * some_slow_function()` to avoid computing the slow part, if that's what you meant. Obviously that replacement would be a speed gain for a sufficiently slow function, and might be equivalent assuming it has no side effects, never returns negative 0, etc.

Comment: You should also choose the floating point operations behavior (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb(v=vs.80).aspx - for Visual Studio, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html flags related to floating point operations - for GCC).

Comment: @artyom.stv your info is really interesting! So i can actually change compilator behaiour with foating point presition for making it faster or more precise... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking, as you seem to be, which is the faster of these 2 operations:

1. Multiplying a vector of numbers including some which are close to 0.0.
2. Running through a vector of numbers setting to 0.0 those which are close to 0.0 and then multiplying the vector.

well, I think that in the limit 1 will be faster than 2.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the array is not a constant but an intermediate result of your program.

Then there would be completely no difference in speed between multiplying by 0 and multiplying by a small number because the machine code executed in both cases is exactly the same. The compiler has no idea about the contents of the array.